# Unable to SSH to GCP Linux server with exact AD username

Tags: windows, active-directory, ssh, google-cloud-platform

First, the standard stuff: I'm on Windows 10 company PC logged in as my Active Directory user. I'm using the built in openssh with either PS or CMD. I generated my RSA key using ssh-keygen, and manually added it to my GCP project for ssh authentication. Now here's where it gets tricky.

When I generated my RSA, it appends my username as "company\username" to the end of my public key. I know this is correct, as when I run "whoami" it shows the same. When I add this ssh key to my GCP project it also adds it as "company\username"; but, when I type ssh user@server or ssh company\username@server Windows is adding an extra backslash "\" to my username, causing authentication to fail:

```
ssh server OR
ssh 'company\username@server'Returns:
company\\username@server: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I've tried many ssh command variations including forward slashes, backslashes, quotations, and yet every single time Windows keeps adding the extra slash.

As a workaround, I've removed the "company\" part from my ssh key; and I've modified my ssh config file to the following:

```
Host *
 User username
```

And this does work - but it's a bit messy; and I'd like to know if there's a way of stopping Windows from inserting that extra backslash. Thanks

EDIT**

Did some further testing and it looks like OpenSSH on Windows is broken. It's even trying to insert an additional backslash during key generation. I will be reporting this to Microsoft directly:

```
PS C:\Users\username> mkdir ~/test

Directory: C:\Users\username

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----            3/6/2020 11:02 AM                test

PS C:\Users\username> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\username/.ssh/id_rsa): ~/test
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "~/test" failed: No such file or directory

C:\Users\username> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\username/.ssh/id_rsa): ~\test
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "~\\test" failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The name after the public key is nothing more than a comment. It can be anything or not exist at all, doesn't matter.

Comment: what happens if you try with `ssh -l username@company server` syntax instead?

Comment: Same error for -l, unfortunately. While I realize that the "name" at the end of the key is a comment, I think GCP is using this as an identifier as it lists the name under the "Username" section of the ssh keys. I have also tried removing the comment altogether but GCP returns the error:  
Invalid key. Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com> or <protocol> <key-blob> google-ssh {"userName":"<username@example.com>","expireOn":"<date>"}

Comment: I should also mention separately that I tried adding the extra backslash "\\" to the user's SSH key in GCP but that also did not work. I couldn't find anything in the GCP documentation about domain names in username, but I imagine Google's systems (being largely Linux based) do not play well with backslashes.

Comment: The double \\ it's because Windows it's trying to escape the special character [Escape Sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=vs-2019)!  How are you generating the ssh-key, why the command you are using it's append a backslash?

Comment: I mentioned it in my original post, but I use the basic "ssh-keygen" command in powershell that is now built into Windows 10. This creates the key and appends my domain username as the comment. I do not know why Windows is registering an additional backslash in my ssh command.

Comment: Which version of powershell you have? On the release notes of powershell 7.0 mark this fix: Fix setting original path of filesystem object to not have extra trailing slash (#10959)

Comment: It seems this issue is still present in the latest version of Powershell 7:

PowerShell 7.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\Users\username> ssh username@server
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\username/.ssh/id_rsa':
PS C:\Users\username> ssh server
company\\username@server: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).